# MySql Date - unexpected results

Tags: mysql, date

Case: I am trying to populate minimum date (JSON Date) from a table to another table for which I have created a join. Example:

```
update table_1 l 
inner join table_2 o on l.xxxxx = o.yyyyy 
inner join (
    select t.some_id_1, t.some_id_2, min(t.DueDate) d 
    from tablexx t 
    where t.abcd = 'som-value' 
    group by some_id_1, some_id_2
    ) t on o.OpportunityId = t.some_id_2 
set update_column_1=Date(t.d), update_colum_2 = t.some_id_1;
```

We can ignore if the logic of join above is correct or not as this is not the actual problem i need help with. The problem comes with the MySql Date Conversion Errors. For example: it gives error like this:

> Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2022-09-22T05:49:00.000Z'

When I do `Select Date('2022-09-22T05:49:00.000Z');` it gives me a correct date

[image: MySql Date]

Now my question is, where I can find more about why is this exactly failing. Why is this truncating? And what is the logic behind the successful or errored conversion. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Study [Date and Time Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html). When you need to use a value which does not match to any allowed format then use STR_TO_DATE() function. https://dbfiddle.uk/Xt2bg0tJ

Comment: If the datetime value which causes your issue due to incorrect format is taken from string-type `t.d` column, and the value is stored in shown format, then you may use, for example, `set update_column_1=SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.d, 'T', 1)`.

Comment: re "what is the logic behind" under sql_mode STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, any date parsing error that just causes a warning in a select statement will become a fatal error in an update statement.

Comment: @Akina, ok, will do. However, it still doesn't make sense, that when I am using Date('some-date-text'), select statement works fine, but not the update one. Why this becomes invalid when I am using it in update?

Comment: *Why this becomes invalid when I am using it in update?* SELECT cannot damage data, it can only provide incorrect output which is not fatal, and warning is enough. Whereas INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE may damage your data - so error is generated.